# s3api get-bucket-location returns null for us-east-1 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Don't know why this happens, but getting null for location call

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.10.62 Python/2.7.11 Darwin/16.1.0 botocore/1.4.52
aws> s3api get-bucket-location --bucket joshuacalloway-us-east-2-bucket
{
    "LocationConstraint": "us-east-2"
}
aws> s3api get-bucket-location --bucket joshuacalloway-us-east-1-bucket
{
    "LocationConstraint": null
}
```

Answer (score 13):

us-east-1 is a specific region as discussed in some AWS doc as below:

https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/developer/leveraging-the-s3-and-s3api-commands/

> For example, if I make a bucket located in the Frankfurt region using the s3 commands:
>
> ```
> $ aws s3 mb s3://myeucentral1bucket --region eu-central-1
> make_bucket: s3://myeucentral1bucket/`
> ```
>
> I can then use s3api get-bucket-location to determine the region of my newly created bucket:
>
> ```
> $ aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket myeucentral1bucket
> {
>     "LocationConstraint": "eu-central-1"
> }
> ```
>
> As shown above, the value of the `LocationConstraint` member in the output JSON is the expected region of the bucket, `eu-central-1`. **Note that for buckets created in the US Standard region, us-east-1, the value of LocationConstraint will be null.** As a quick reference to how location constraints correspond to regions, refer to the AWS Regions and Endpoints Guide.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

> If you use a region other than the US East (N. Virginia) endpoint to create a bucket, you must set the LocationConstraint bucket parameter to the same region

Answer (score 1):

When you create an S3 bucket, the bucket is created in a specific region. Knowing the region that your bucket is in is essential for a variety of use cases such as transferring files across buckets located in different regions and making requests that require Signature Version 4 signing. However, you may not know or remember where your bucket is located. Fortunately by using the s3api commands, you can determine your bucket’s region.

For example, if I make a bucket located in the Frankfurt region using the s3 commands:

$ aws s3 mb s3://myeucentral1bucket --region eu-central-1
make_bucket: s3://myeucentral1bucket/
I can then use s3api get-bucket-location to determine the region of my newly created bucket:

$ aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket myeucentral1bucket
{
"LocationConstraint": "eu-central-1"
}
As shown above, the value of the LocationConstraint member in the output JSON is the expected region of the bucket, eu-central-1.

**Note that for buckets created in the US Standard region, us-east-1, the value of LocationConstraint will be null.**

As a quick reference to how location constraints correspond to regions, refer to the AWS Regions and Endpoints Guide.

https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/developer/leveraging-the-s3-and-s3api-commands/